# In a -50°F blizzard, how to generate enough body heat to avoid frostbite?

Tags: safety, frostbite

The Winter is coming soon (in ~3 months) here in North Dakota and I'd like to be better prepared than last winter. I have hit a weird personal threshold [mere 5 degrees] that I cannot seem to comprehend: I can walk outside comfortably even at -42°F (-41 C) blizzard but when it was -47°F (-44 C), it was brutal and my hands were getting frostnip just after 20 minutes, despite having thick, heavy, large mittens.
I was wading through almost knee-deep snow, which at -25°F (-32 C) means I would be unzipping layers, as it's simply too hot. But not at -47°F (-44 C). Now, the air itself was quite warm - around -35 (-37 C), which without wind is [obviously] perfectly fine and comfortable.

But the snow particles were like thousand needles biting into my face (I only had a regular hat with ear flaps that can be closed via clips, no facemask or anything). Even my Siberian Husky seems to have hit her limit - every single blizzard (including the -42°F (-41 C) a week ago), she waltzes happily against the wind. This time, after 5 tries, she turned her back and just let the wind push her.It was too much for a Husky.

There is a possibility that the interpolated data at the weather app were incorrect, as I talked next week to a friend who lived 30 miles NW and they got around -65°F (-54 C) windchill.

Given the fact that we have sometimes 3 storms in a week and I need to walk my Husky 4-5 times a day, I cannot avoid the exposure and simply must go out even when infrastructure everywhere around shuts down for a week.

Example - there was one week last winter, where every single time I went out (4-5x a day), there was a storm (I managed to sleep through the quiet times and "save" my walks for blizzards/storms).

So, what can I do to make the half-hour trip outside less miserable and more safe? Also, I'm pretty sure I am not equipped for -65°F (-54 C)...

Comment: Frostbite, if I understand it properly is not all about generating internal body heat, but rather avoiding exposed skin to the elements. Of course body heat may play a part in it also.

Comment: @Ken: Well, the only exposed skin is your face (the front). As I learnt last winter, beard surprisingly provides significant shield, so I've been growing it last ~8 months, which will certainly help, in coming months. My noggin is kinda large (adequate with 6'3" height), and of all 3 face masks that I bought last winter, I could barely put my head into one, and it was like a vice. So, no face mask for me, maybe in some specialty shop, for $200...

Comment: @Ken: Body heat is important - from experience. If I increase my walking speed, I can remove a clothing layer. Hell, if I walk fast, I can walk without gloves (up to certain temp) even at -20, for half an hour (if there is no windchill). But, this particular blizzard, at -47 'F, even wading through snow didn't warm me up enough. Maybe as an additional exercise I should put my Husky onto a sled and haul her :) ?

Comment: I don't understand what the point is when even the husky cannot tolerate lower than -42°F. Do you mean the temperature drops after the walk has begun?

Comment: @Vane: The "point" is that Husky needs to do its business. Every day. Few times each day. Just because it's around -50 'F, doesn't mean she won't take her sweet time and preciously keep searching for the sacred poo*ing grounds. Trust me, when it's that cold, you'll definitely prefer to spend 25-30 minutes in one go, than try to go out 4 more times (even if shorter), but unsuccesfully. It's not an easy thing to get ready. Takes few minutes to put on all the layers.

Comment: @Vane: I don't think the temperature really drops during half an hour in any measurable way. The -42F was one day. The -47 F was different day. While the wind speed was roughly the same (e.g. brutal), the -47 F was unwalkable against the wind. I spent last 3 years in Montana and Dakotas, but this blizzard was the worst thing ever. Even my Husky, who always welcomes such challenge, hops always against the wind, she could not. She tried. Like 4-5 times. Then she gave me the "WTF" look, and turned around and let blizzard push her. That never happened before,but she's an indoor Husky-e.g. spoiled!

Comment: I sense you're really proud of your supposed resistance to cold, but it's really annoying and unnecessary to formulate the question. It sort of hurts my eyes and makes me cringe a little bit. Just a friendly tip.

Comment: In regards to the 2nd comment, Maybe instead of a conventional facemask wear layers of a shemagh ("tactical scarf") or something similar, i would think any amount of exposed face you can cut down on would be huge plus.

Comment: @QuantumBrick: Unnecessary ? So, I should just keep suffering, if all it takes is simply ask the question on a forum full of people that spend months in sub-zero temperatures [on expeditions] or at least days [doing winter sports] ? Most of them are, at one point or another, exposed to such conditions and could offer some valuable advice. Only a sociopath would "advise" to never learn and rather keep suffering...

Comment: @NateW : Thanks for the tip! I will google it. Never heard of that term. Perhaps there will be more interesting stuff at that store. I don't often wear a scarf as it's just a nuisance to put on 5 times a day, and in strong winds it can be more of a hindrance then help...

Comment: @QuantumBrick : "Supposed cold resistance" :) ? I'll have you know that I grew up in a climate that routinely had below -30 windchill, yet till I started attending university, I only had daily access to an outside outhouse. When a -30 draft enters you from below, you *DO* build up cold resistance whether you want or not. The most you can wear there is a thick sweater,no gloves obviously and no scarf either(makes the process very hard). Frostnip was a part of daily life and we learnt very early (pre-school age) how brutally painful defrosting in a bucket of water is, so made sure to avoid it :)